# duplicate mongo record in same collection

Tags: mongodb, duplicate-data

In mongo I have a collections with records. These record are very complex. Now I would like to duplicate one of them.

I can easily select the one

```
mongo> var row = db.barfoo.find({"name":"bar"});
```

Now I actually don't know what to do. I don't know what is in `row` because I cannot find a way to print its content. How can I change specific properties and finally insert this modified row again

```
mongo> db.barfoo.insert(row);
```

thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that you're working directly inside the mongo shell.

Once you have your *document* (not a row :P ), you'd modify the properties in the same way you would a normal JavaScript object:

```
var doc = db.barfoo.findOne( { "name": "bar" } );
doc.name = "Mr Bar";
```

Note that the [`find()` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) returns a cursor, so if you're looking to extract a single document, you should use the [`findOne()` function](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/). This function returns a single document.

If you are interested in duplicating numerous documents, you can use the `find()` function and iterate over the cursor to retrieve each document:

```
db.barfoo.find( { "name": "bar" } ).forEach( function( doc ){
  doc.name = "Mr Bar";
}
```

After you change the relevant properties, you can use the `insert/save` methods to persist the data back to mongo. Don't forget to change/delete the `_id` attribute so that you'll actually create a new document.

---

As a side note, in order to view the contents of an object in the mongo shell, you can use the [`print()` function](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/#print). If you want a more visually appealing output, you could use `printjson()`.

Comment: Doesn't `find` return a cursor? He should iterate through it to actually get the name (or record), shouldn't he?

Comment: I'm sure you mean `findOne` not `find_one` :P

Comment: @lascort ARRGGHH!!!! Jumping from language to language always trips me up! You're very patient with your downvotes ;)

Comment: So I have a variable that contains a large amount of documents. When I execute the forEach on it, it completely breaks and returns nothing without any error messages, and erases the contents of the var previously containing an array of documents

Comment: Hi @AymonFournier - please create a new post if you have a different question from this one.

Answer (score 7):

You must change value `_id` - generate new:

```
var row = db.barfoo.findOne({"name":"bar"});
row._id = ObjectId();
db.barfoo.insert(row);
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Mongo will create an `_id` attribute if one is missing. I don't think that you have to manually create it like this - [see here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/)

Comment: @Lix I'm using mongo 3.2.8 and I needed the `_id` creation to get this to work.